# jsonexception: value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject Banking Application

Tags: android

I am trying to create a form in android and insert the data into database.
I am hosting it on 000webhost and using PHPMyAdmin , MYSQL for the database.
I am getting a TOAST with an Exception of :jsonexception: value br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject, when I,m trying to click save button.

Here is my XML Code(createAccount.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".createAccount">


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="343dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="1 ) Account Number :"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/accounNumber"
    android:layout_width="324dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"

    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:text="2 ) Bank Name :"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/bankNames"
    android:layout_width="355dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:entries="@array/bank_arrays" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
    android:text="3) Bank City :"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cityNames"
    android:layout_width="355dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="339dp"
    android:entries="@array/city_arrays" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveandnext"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="214dp"
    android:background="#afe933a6"
    android:text="Save and Next" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cityNames"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="311dp"
    android:text="4) Branch Name/IFSC Code :" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ifscCode_branchname"
    android:layout_width="332dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="264dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

createAccount.java:

```
package com.example.admin.loginapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class createAccount extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
Spinner BankName,BankCity;
EditText Acc_Num,IFSC_Code_BranchName;
    private static String URL_ACCOUNT_DETAILS="https://haematoid-circulati.000webhostapp.com/account_details.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);
        //addListenerOnButton();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");


        BankName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bankNames);
        BankCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cityNames);
        Acc_Num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accounNumber);
        IFSC_Code_BranchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ifscCode_branchname);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveandnext);


               button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        final String bankname=BankName.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                        final String bank_city=BankCity.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                        final String accountnumber=Acc_Num.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String ifsc_code_branchName=IFSC_Code_BranchName.getText().toString().trim();

                        if(!ifsc_code_branchName.isEmpty() || !accountnumber.isEmpty()) {
                            account_details_func(email, bankname, bank_city, ifsc_code_branchName, accountnumber);
                        } else{
                            Acc_Num.setError("Please Enter Account Number");
                            IFSC_Code_BranchName.setError("Please Enter IFSC code");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


    private void account_details_func(final String email, final String bankname, final String bank_city, final String ifsc_code_branchName, final String accountnumber) {
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ACCOUNT_DETAILS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success= jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
                  //  int account_number=jsonObject.getInt("account_number");

                    if(success){
                        Toast.makeText(createAccount.this,"Saved Successfully !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(createAccount.this,depositMoney1.class);
                        //intent.putExtra("account_number",account_number);
                        createAccount.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(createAccount.this,"Error !!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(createAccount.this," Error is : " +e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(createAccount.this," Error is ::: " +error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();

                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("bankname",bankname);
                params.put("bank_city",bank_city);
                params.put("accountnumber",accountnumber);
                params.put("ifsc_code_branchName",ifsc_code_branchName);
                return params ;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    }
```

account_details.php:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id7375066_ajinkyaphand", "9028836116", "id7375066_bankapp");


    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $bankname = $_POST['bankname'];
    $bank_city = $_POST['bank_city'];
    $accountnumber = $_POST['accountnumber'];
    $ifsc_code_branchName = $_POST['ifsc_code_branchName'];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO account_details (Account_Number,Email_id,Bank_Name  ,Bank_City,Branch_Name/IFSC_Code) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "issss", $accountnumber,$email, $bankname,$bank_city ,$ifsc_code_branchName);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Please can some guide me as I'm new to android.

My Response from POSTMAN - 
URL-

```
https://haematoid-circulati.000webhostapp.com/account_details.php?Account_Number=12456&Bank_City=Pune&Branch_Name/IFSC_Code=narhe&Bank_Name=Bank Of maharashtra&Email_id=ajinkyaphand@gmail.com
```

Response:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>5</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: bankname in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>6</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: bank_city in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>7</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: accountnumber in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>8</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: ifsc_code_branchName in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>9</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>12</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in
<b>/storage/ssd2/066/7375066/public_html/account_details.php</b> on line
<b>13</b>
<br />
{"success":true}
```

Comment: Copy your text that you want to get, or send.

Comment: Share your response received after api request.

Comment: I have Shared My response.